# How to fetch events just for the month and year displaying by the user?

Tags: fullcalendar

i use VueJS 3 with type script and Full Calendar V6.
I need to load events when user click on Next or Previous month/year.
I need to fetch events just for the month and year displaying by the user.

I dont want to make a query that retrieves all the events in the database.

I use the "events:" property in calendarOptions.

[image: 1]

But the only way I found is to pass an asynchronous request to this property (events:). This property will then distribute the events properly in the calendar.

[image: 2]

How to make a dynamic and parameterized request, according to the month and year consulted by the user?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before posting, please don't post images of code, data or errors. This info is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: `I need to load events when user click on Next or Previous`...fullCalendar takes care of this automatically for you if you use a [json event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) or a [function-based event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) - in those scenarios fullCalendar will provide your code with the start and end dates of the time period the calendar is now showing, so that you can filter and return the correct events accordingly.

Comment: THX for your reply. Sorry for the format of my question, this is the first time I've posted. What is a JsonFeed exactly? If I pass the backend url directly to "events:", I get a json parsing error in the frontend. So I have to make a first API request to get the events in a variable. It is this variable that I pass to "events:". Ok it works, but I'll still need to dynamically retrieve the events according to the month and the year consulted, in order to use this data elsewhere. Do you have an idea how to do this? 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: `I get a json parsing error in the frontend`...this suggests your backend does not return valid JSON. That is probably something you can fix, if you wrote that code.

Comment: `So I have to make a first API request to get the events in a variable`...yes but you're not really doing it the right way, for fullcalendar to help you. If getting the JSON feed working directly is not possible then - as I mentioned above - use the [function-based events feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) - declare that function, make your API request inside it (passing the provided start and end dates to the backend so you can filter it), then return the events to fullCalendar via the provided callback. The documentation has an example.

Comment: Assuming I understand how to use the event (as a function) with vueJS, how do I pass the value of "start: info.start.valueOf()" and "end: info.end.valueOf()", depending on the month the user is viewing? How do I get the start and end value of the month the user is viewing when he clicks on the prev and next buttons?

Comment: `How do I get the start and end value of the month the user is viewing when he clicks on the prev and next buttons`...it will happen automatically. Fullcalendar will execute the function you provided to the `events` option, and into it will be passed the start and end dates that the calendar has just moved to. As you say, these will be in the `info.start` and `info.end` variables. Your function code can of course then pass these values to your server.